# How do I incorporate SelectKBest in an SKlearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a text classifier with sklearn. The idea is to:

1. Vectorize training corpus using
   [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)
2. Select the top 20,000 features that result (or using all features if the resultant number is below 20k) using [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)
3. Feed these features into a [Logistic Regression Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

I've set it up successfully as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
x_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_train["input"])
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=min(20000, x_train.shape[1]))
selector.fit(x_train, df_train["label"].values)
x_train = selector.transform(x_train)
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(x_train, df_train["label"])
```

I would now like to wrap all this up into a pipeline, and share the pipeline so it can be used by others for their own text data. Yet, I can't figure how to get SelectKBest to achieve the same behavior as it did above, i.e. accept min(20000, n_features from vectorizer output) as k. If I were to simply leave it as k=20000 as below, the pipeline doesn't work (throws an error) when fitting new corpora with less than 20k vectorized features.

```
pipe = Pipeline([
            ("vect",TfidfVectorizer()),
            ("selector",SelectKBest(f_classif, k=20000)),
            ("clf",LogisticRegression())])
```

Comment: The error is due to [this function check here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py#L521). You need to subclass the SelectKBest and implement your own check to see if the `k` is less than the shape of `X` or not. If not, then assign new `k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vivek kumar pointed out you need to override the `_check_params` method of `SelectKBest` and add your logic to it as shown below:

```
class MySelectKBest(SelectKBest):
    def _check_params(self, X, y):
        if (self.k >= X.shape[1]):
            warnings.warn("Less than %d number of features found, so setting k as %d" % (self.k, X.shape[1]),
                      UserWarning)
            self.k = X.shape[1]
        if not (self.k == "all" or 0 <= self.k):
            raise ValueError("k should be >=0, <= n_features = %d; got %r. "
                             "Use k='all' to return all features."
                             % (X.shape[1], self.k))
```

I have also set a warning in case if the number of features found is less than the threshold set. Now let's see a working example of the same:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import warnings

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'comp.graphics',
              'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware', 'comp.sys.mac.hardware',
              'comp.windows.x', 'misc.forsale', 'rec.autos']
newsgroups = fetch_20newsgroups(categories=categories)
y_true = newsgroups.target

# newsgroups result in 47K odd features after performing TFIDF vectorizer

# Case 1: When K < No. of features - the regular case
pipe = Pipeline([
            ("vect",TfidfVectorizer()),
            ("selector",MySelectKBest(f_classif, k=30000)),
            ("clf",LogisticRegression())])

pipe.fit(newsgroups.data, y_true)
pipe.score(newsgroups.data, y_true)
#0.968

#Case 2: When K > No. of cases - the one with an issue

pipe = Pipeline([
            ("vect",TfidfVectorizer()),
            ("selector",MySelectKBest(f_classif, k=50000)),
            ("clf",LogisticRegression())])

pipe.fit(newsgroups.data, y_true)
UserWarning: Less than 50000 number of features found, so setting k as 47407

pipe.score(newsgroups.data, y_true)
#0.9792
```